# How to see the individual fivestar ratings in a view?

Tags: views, rating

How do I design a view to see every user's fivestar rating? I want to see a node, and below that list all users' ratings (and not connect it to comments). The only thing I've been able to do is list every user that has rated a node and get the value of their vote (percent) but if I change the value to show the "rate widget", so that I can see the nice fivestar rating, it can either show me the logged-in user's rating or the average rating. It will not show me the actual user's rating.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can create a relationship to Votes, and then you can show the users who voted and their vote values.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That is indeed what I did, but again, it will only show the percentage (which is correct), but if I want to see the actual fivestar widget, it will only let me see the logged in user's rating or the average, not the value of the star.

Comment: Ah, your best bet then would to just build your own with a views_pre_render hook. Get the rating, then generate the number of stars based on the value.